# C++ Inheritance Question edit: more troubles

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class MessageHandler and 2 derived classes, MessageHandler_CB and MessageHandler_DQ.

The derived classes redefine the handleMessage(...) method. MH_DQ processes a message and puts the result in a deque while MH_CB processes the message and then executes a callback function.

The base class has a static callback function that I pass along with a this pointer to a library which calls the static callback when a new message is available for processing.

My problem comes when I am in the static callback with a void * pointing to either a MH_DQ or a MH_CB.  If I cast it to the base class the empty MessageHandler::handleMessage(...) method is called, rather than the version in the appropriate derived class.

What is the best way to address this situation from a design perspective and/or what language features might help me to implement a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Okay, the virtual method did not work like magic.  There is a twist to the story.  I have a static method in the base class and a pure virtual member function to handle the message processing, but I want to first call a member function in the pure virtual base class to preprocess the message before I route it to the derived class.

So I have :

```
class MH {

...

static int CallBackFunction(MessageData *md, void *this_ptr) {
  ((MH *)this_ptr)->preprocess(md);
  return 1;
}

virtual int preprocess(MessageData *md) {
  // do some stuff
  . . .

  handleMessage(md);
  return 1;
}

virtual void handleMessage(MessageData *) = 0;

};

class MH_CB : public MH {

...

void handleMessage(MessageData *md) {
  // do something
  ...
}
};

class MH_DQ : public MH {
...

void handleMessage(MessageData *md) {
  // do something different
  ...
}
};
```

Unfortunately, this code produces a run-time error that a pure virtual function is being called.  Any thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Make the original method call virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a void* in the callback - pass a pointer to the base class, and declare handleMessage to be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `virtual` keyword to the declaration/definition of the method in the base class.

In fact if the method in the base class is never supposed to run then you can specify that it's [pure virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2) to declare it with no body at all, instead of defining an empty body:

```
class MessageHandler
{
public:
    virtual void handleMessage(...) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the handleMessage() as virtual by prefixing `void handleMessage()` or whatever declaration in the base class with the word `virtual`.  Then, make sure that the derived classes implement the exact same message signature (i.e. same return type and parameter types).

Also- instead of a void* use a MessageHandlerBase* (or whatever is appropriate).  Then you don't need to cast.  Casting is often the sign of a logic error on the part of the programmer.